# Sort on T-SQL unioned query with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, common-table-expression

I need to do a sort on a T-SQL unioned query. No matter how I write the query, I'm getting a syntax error once I introduce the `ORDER BY` clause.

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'

#### T-SQL query

```
WITH s1
AS (select '1' as id
    union
    select '4' as id
    union
    select '2' as id
    union
    select '3' as id
    union
    select '5' as id
   ),
     s2
AS (select '4' as id,
           100 as val
    union
    select '1' as id,
           500 as val
    union
    select '3' as id,
           700 as val
    union
    select '2' as id,
           800 as val
   )
(select '9' as id,
        700 as val) -- id 9 should stay on first row
UNION
(select s1.id,
        s2.val
 from s1
     Left join s2
         on s1.id = s2.id  --Order by s2.val causing a syntax error )
```

#### Query output

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 800 |
| 3 | 700 |
| 4 | 100 |
| 5 | NULL |
| 9 | 700 |

#### Desired output

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 700 |
| 4 | 100 |
| 1 | 500 |
| 3 | 700 |
| 2 | 800 |
| 5 | NULL |

Comment: @DaleK That would sort the whole result set. I need only the second view to be sorted . Please look at the desired output. Notice how id 7 with val of 700 needs to stay on top.

Comment: You can only sort the whole union "thing".

Comment: The above is a demo query. Adding another column is not a possible or practical solution in my case. Thanks!

Comment: It's interesting that following isn't allowed in the sort: `order by case when id = '9' then 0 else 1 end, val` - gives `Invalid column name 'id'`

Comment: Check the *full error* @siggemannen , it also states "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator." A common workaround is to use a derived table or CTE.

Comment: yes, but id appear in the select of both queries! `SELECT '9' AS id
, 700 AS val
UNION ALL
SELECT s1.id,
        s2.val
FROM s1
LEFT JOIN s2
         ON s1.id = s2.id 
order by case when id = '9' then 0 else 1 end, val`

Comment: it's almost like columns are "hidden" from the unioned order by

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add an additional column specially for ordered, but don't select it e.g.

```
SELECT id, val
FROM (
  SELECT '9' AS id, 700 AS val, 1 AS SortOrder
  UNION ALL -- Always use union all where you can for performance
  SELECT s1.id, s2.val, 0 AS SortOrder
  FROM s1
  LEFT JOIN s2 ON s1.id = s2.id
) x
ORDER BY SortOrder DESC, val
```

Answer (score 0):

Your end part should be like this for desired output.

```
UNION all
select *
from (
select top 100 percent s1.id,
    s2.val
from s1
 Left join s2
     on s1.id = s2.id  
order by val
) sub_query
```

**Edit:**
TOP 100 percent doesn't work in newer versions.
(TOP [hard coded value]) will work but it would not be a clean solution).

Comment: that isn't guaranteed to be sorted properly

Comment: yes it will keep the sorting

Comment: The only way the guarantee the order of the results returned is an `ORDER BY` in the scope that *returns* the data. This is like the "hack" where people used to be a `TOP` and `ORDER BY` in a `VIEW`'s definition. In newer versions of SQL Server, I believe it's "clever" enough to ignore the clauses, as they achieve nothing. I wouldn't be surprised if the same occurs here.

Answer (score 0):

The `order by` clause needs to be applied to the final `select`. You can use a subquery to perform the `union` and then select the results of the subquery and order them. A `case` expression in the `order by` clause will force the `'9'` row to the top of the results.

```
WITH
  s1 AS ( select id from ( values ( '1' ), ( '4' ), ( '2' ), ( '3' ), ( '5' ) ) as s1v( id ) ),
  s2 AS ( select id, val from ( values ( '4', 100 ), ( '1', 500 ), ( '3', 700 ), ( '2', 800 ) ) as s2v( id, val ) )
select id, val
  from (
    select '9' as id, 700 as val -- id 9 should stay on first row
    union
    select s1.id, s2.val
      from s1 left join s2 on s1.id = s2.id
    ) as Antoine
  order by case when id = '9' then 0 else 1 end, -- Force '9' to be the first row.
    val;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MlvpG1-r).